# Magento : Order with status Processing, complete is not visible on front end

Tags: xml, magento, xml-parsing, magento-1.7

I have a magento estore and I am facing an issue with showing the orders in user account.

The orders with status "Pending" is getting shown in the front end user account in My Orders section but the orders with other statuses like "Processing", "Complete", etc. are not showing.

I have checked the config.xml file for sales placed at : /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml

It has the visible_on_front property set to 1 for all the states.

```
<new translate="label">
                    <label>New</label>
                    <statuses>
                        <pending default="1"/>
                    </statuses>
                    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                </new>
                <pending_payment translate="label">
                    <label>Pending Payment</label>
                    <statuses>
                        <pending_payment default="1"/>
                    </statuses>
                </pending_payment>
                <processing translate="label">
                    <label>Processing</label>
                    <statuses>
                        <processing default="1"/>
                    </statuses>
                    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                </processing>
                <complete translate="label">
                    <label>Complete</label>
                    <statuses>
                        <complete default="1"/>
                    </statuses>
                    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                </complete>
                <closed translate="label">
                    <label>Closed</label>
                    <statuses>
                        <closed default="1"/>
                    </statuses>
                    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                </closed>
```

My site URL is : http://www.gionee.co.in/estore

Let me know how to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You all. I have found the solution to this : 
Just go to :

```
 app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/History.php
```

and comment this line

```
->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
```

It will work fine. I am marking this question as closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xml which can be added in your module's config file to show statuses on frontend:

```
<config>
<global>
    <sales>
        <order>
            <states>
                <pending_payment translate="label">
                    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                </pending_payment>
            </states>
        </order>
    </sales>
</global>
</config>
```